# RowCallbackHandler loades rows info memory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to query a big dataset from DB. Actually I'm gonna use pagination parameters (limit and offset) to avoid loading large dataset into heap. For that purpose I'm trying to fetch rows with `RowCallBackHadler` interface, because docs say `An interface used by JdbcTemplate for processing rows of a ResultSet on a per-row basis.` and also I've read advices to use that interface to deal with rows one by one.
But something goes wrong every time when I try to fetch data. Here my code below and also screenshot from visualVM with heap space graphic which indicates that all rows were loaded into memory. Query, which I'm trying to execute, returns something around 1.5m rows in DB.

```
    // here just sql query, map with parameters for query, pretty simple RowCallbackHandler
    jdbcTemplate.query(queryForExecute, params, new RowCallbackHandler() {
        @Override
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        }
    });
```

heap via visualVM:
[image]

**update:** I made a mistake when called `rs.next()`, but removing this line didn't change the situation with loading rows into memory at all

Comment: You're not using `RowCallbackHandler` the way it's [supposed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/610de3ae786812f332b71a7453a67afd39834a03/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.java#L50) to be used: You should only process row and not call `row.next()`. The way you're using it, you will always miss first row.

Comment: @Adarsh thanks for your rely! I've recognized my mistakes and fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was with understanding documentation. Doc says

> An interface used by JdbcTemplate for processing rows of a ResultSet on a per-row basis.

Actually my code does things in right way: returns me a ResultSet which contains all row (because limit is not defined). I had no confidence that adding LIMIT to any sql query will work good and decided to implement LIMIT via RowCallbackHandler and it was a bad idea, because LIMIT works great with all type of sql queries (complex and simple).